# raise custom error based on different conditions in resource_owner_authenticator in config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, doorkeeper

I want to raise custom error and customise error response based on different conditions.
for authentication, I have a few conditions where a user is not authenticated, for example,
not active user, user profile is incomplete etc etc.

I followed this, [#315](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/315) , I configured the same but execution stops at line where it raises the custom doorkeeper error.

`Doorkeeper.configure do
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(user_login_path(return_to: request.fullpath))
    raise Doorkeeper::Errors::OwnError unless @user.status == 'active'
  end
end`

Please help if anybody have any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue until I read the NEWS.md file:

```
- [#749] Allow user to raise authorization error with custom messages.
  Under `resource_owner_authenticator` block a user can
  `raise Doorkeeper::Errors::DoorkeeperError.new('custom_message')`
```

For password flow POST /oauth/token:

```
 resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
    raise Doorkeeper::Errors::DoorkeeperError.new('custom_message')
 end
```

Gives a response like:

```
 {
      "error": "custom_message",
      "error_description": "The authorization server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request."
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have found the answer already, in case you haven't:

Add this to the controller where you use doorkeeper_authorize!

```
def doorkeeper_unauthorized_render_options(error: nil)
  response_hash = { status: false, description: error.description, expired: false }
  response_hash[:expired] = true if error.description == "The access token expired"
  { json: response_hash }
end
```

Here respnse_hash would be the error returned.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to raise a custom error, you can do something like that with i18n, it's better.

```
# config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb
Doorkeeper.configure do
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    raise Doorkeeper::Errors::DoorkeeperError.new('foo') if @bar
  end
end
```

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  doorkeeper:
    errors:
      messages:
        foo: Here we are!
```

You can always override `Doorkeeper::TokensController#create` to manage the error as long as your error is inherited from `Doorkeeper::Errors::DoorkeeperError`.

```
def create
  super
rescue ::Doorkeeper::Errors::DoorkeeperError => e
  # Do something here. 
  handle_token_exception(e)
end
```